# WPF Combobox item style

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

Can someone please direct me on how to style my combobox that has a checkbox as a comboboxitem. I tried to find a duplicate to no avail, so if this is a duplicate questions please let me know the correct one. The behavior that is currently happening is that when the mouse hovers over an item it makes the background and foreground black. What I'd like is the background to maybe be gray or the foreground to be white white mouse is hovering over. I can't for the life of me figure out the right style color brush to make this happen...any help would be great!

Here's the xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PromptFilterList}">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Item.Description}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Here's what happens, as you can see the letters are not legible when mouse is over item:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I Hope this may help you.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
     <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Border" Value="1" />
     <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{your requirement}" />
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{your requirement}" />
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{your requirement}" />                            
     </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```